# preventing angular to run in non displayed DOM elements

Tags: angularjs, authorization

lets say I have a HTML structure like this

```
<myHandler>
    <element_1 ng-controller="..." ng-init="">
        content
    </element_1>
    <element_2 ng-controller="..." ng-init="">
        content
    </element_2>
</myHandler>
```

So, my css is saying element_2 has display: none;

how to tell angular not to run on these lements, that are hidden?
and run only (once) when they are visible?

to clarify the case more, the myHandler is handling authorization and is displaying  element_1/element_2 depending on the permissions.

so I don't want to initialized element_2 if it has no permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of keeping display none ,just keep an attribute ng-if with a flag variable 
because if we use ng-if then no element is added into the dom or if no element added then no controller will get instantiated.

```
<myHandler>
    <element_1 ng-controller="..." ng-init="">
        content
    </element_1>
    <sample ng-if="isDisplay">
    <element_2  ng-controller="..." ng-init="">
        content
    </element_2>
</sample>
</myHandler>
```

Comment: ok, found that ng-switch would be more appropriate for this case...how can I controller this in myHandler directive?

Comment: maybe not, because I would need to have a wrapper element with switch on controller than. Thanks for the input